# Why cant I use the variable "i" from my constructor in other member functions? C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on creating a Bank program for my Programming methodology and, for some reason, I can't seem to use the value that I assign to the variable `i` in the constructor in any of the other member functions. For instance, if the user input is `6` and `i` is calculated to be 0.005 by the constructor, that value (0.005) is not passed to the `MakePayment` function. Instead, `i` is reset to zero.

Can anyone shed some light on this? My code is below.

```
  Loan_Data::Loan_Data(double p, double n, double i)
{
    cout << "Enter the loan amount: $";
    cin >> p;
    cout << "Enter the loan length: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter your credit score: ";
    cin >> i;

        i = i / 100;
    i = i / 12;
    n = n * 12;
    Bal = p;
        A = (p * ((i * pow(1 + i, n)) / (pow(1 + i, n) - 1)));

        cout << "A is: " << A << endl;
        cout << "Bal is: " << Bal << endl;
        cout << "i is: " << i << endl;
}
void Loan_Data::MakePayment(double pay)
{
        cout << "i is: " << i << endl;
        cout << "Bal is: " << Bal << endl;
    cout << "Enter payment amount: $";
    cin >> pay;

        cout << "Bal is: " << Bal << endl;

    Bal = ((i + 1) * Bal) - pay;
        cout << "i is: " << i << endl;
        cout << "Bal is: " << Bal << endl;
        cout << "Pay is: " << pay << endl;
        cout << "A is: " << A << endl;
        A = pay;
        cout << "A is: " << A << endl;
}
```

Comment: what is class declaration?  is `i` a member variable?  if so then the constructor has an argument that is also `i`.

Comment: This is just a mess...attempting to pass parameters, then cin them?

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to use `i` in other member functions? `i` is just a local variable in your constructor. It is not possible to use it in other member functions. It does not exist in other member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i = i / 100;` is setting the parameter `i`, not the member variable `i` (assuming such variable exists). The parameter is hiding the member.

You can fix this by either using `this->i` (i.e. `this->i = i / 100`), or changing the parameter name so it doesn't collide with the member variable's name.

But perhaps you should just get rid of the parameter, given that you don't actually use it (`cin >> i;` nukes whatever value it had, making it totally pointless to pass it in the first place).

Comment: You are correct in assuming that the member vairable exists, and using 'this->' fixed the issue. I don't know why my professor specified the use of i as an arguement in the constructor and also as a member variable, but thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post all your code but I assume that you have a `i` attribute in your class.

The issue is that you're taking `i` as a parameter in your constructor so the `i` inside your class is hidden. Since you're not actually using the value of `i`, `p` or `n` you can simply remove them from the parameters of your constructor like this:

```
Loan_Data::Loan_Data(){
   double p, double n;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see your whole class definition. However, what i can see is the problem with this function:->

Loan_Data::Loan_Data(double p, double n, double i);

As you've said the 'i' variable(a member variable of your class) is not getting updated.This is because of the variable name collission in your function, in which local variable is always preferred. So your local variable gets modified(whose scope is limited to this function).

I think you should get rid of this variable or by using this->i(complete specification) to avoid confusion just like cornstalks said.